# 32 bit *.ocx file to IDL file to *_h.h and *_i.c file converted to a 64 bit *.ocx file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, activex, ole

This is convoluted so I may lose some you right away. We have a 32 bit activex control purchased from a vendor a long time ago for an in-house program developed with Visual c++ 6.0. Now, we are going to update our program using Visual Studio 2013 to have both a 32 bit and 64 bit platform. The vendor no longer supports c++ nor do they have a 64 bit version of this activex file. I am able to build the software using Visual Studio 2013 32 bit and the activex control works perfectly. But, due to platform differences, building the software using 64 bit, the software all works except the part that needs the activex control.
Now I ran the OLE/COM Object viewer (OleView.exe) and successfully created an IDL file from the activex ocx file. Then, I was able to compile the IDL file (after some debugging) to create *_h.h and *_i.c files.
The question: Is there a simple and elegant way to take those files and rebuild the activex in 64 bit platform?

Comment: You do realize those are just files that are about the interfaces?  To rebuild an ActiveX control takes all the rest of the source files.  You should ask why you really need a 64-bit version?  Do you need the increased resources and memory, or is it just marketing, or a bug up some boss's butt?  You can't simple recompile those files to 64-bit.  If you're using VS 2013 (and ask why not 2017?), then you'd extract the type library from the OCX, save it as a .TLB file, and then #import into your project.  Google for DllSurrogate.  No matter what your 32-bit OCX has to run in 32-bit process.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson, thank you for the comment. Even though the project is only used in house, we require DLLs from customers who have requested we move to 64 bit.  I do not know why VS 2013 was chosen. If you create an answer that states it can't be done with the parameters I have provided, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just recompile the header files and .c files that comprise the interface of the OCX to create a 64-bit OCX.  The OCX consists of the interface files and many other files which are the implementation of the control.  Trying to do it as you are won't work.